# Which is best for browser detection: PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, browser-detection

What I want to do is simple: during signin process, if system detects that someone else signed with same credentials, to notify user about ip addresses and browsers that currently signed in. That's why want to use PHP or Javascript to record browser name into database during signin. Do you know any good script for this purpose?

Please give link or post code.

Comment: PHP 'knows' nothing about a browser except of what is sent as User-Agent in the http headers. You can use http://www.php.net/get_browser for UA header, but you can not 100% rely on that information as there are a lot of addons to the browsers changing UA.

Comment: If it has to run on the server, then it should be written in whatever you're running on the server.

Comment: PHP is not for browser detection..!

Comment: This seems to be a legitimate question. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Java script is best for browser detection , because in php the information available about browsers come from the http user agent header, as this can be customized we cannot make sure about the browser. But if we use javascript we get the correct result. U can use the jquery built in function to check the browser and its version .

Example: Show the browser info.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:green; font-weight:bolder; margin:3px 0 0 10px; }
  div { color:blue; margin-left:20px; font-size:14px; }
  span { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Browser info:</p>

<script>
    jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
      $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
                .appendTo( document.body );
    });</script>

</body>
</html>


Browser info:
mozilla : true
version : 10.0
```

Check the documentation
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: Available flags are:

    webkit (as of jQuery 1.4)
    safari (deprecated)
    opera
    msie
    mozilla

You need to check these flags , go through the documentation in detail

Comment: The jQuery documentation you link explains that it is doing nothing more than a PHP implementation; parsing the reported User-Agent. This code is susceptible to the same spoofing problems as any UA parser.